# If $X$ is exponential, why does this hold?

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ is an exponential distribution, why does $$P(X = x \cap X < c) = P(X = x)$$ hold? Feels like I missed something trivial here.

Comment: No not that one.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $\mathbb{P}(X>x+c|X>c) = \mathbb{P}(X>x)$?

Comment: Yes I am sure it is not memoryless. BUt I figured out the answer to my own problem. See my own answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the exponential distribution is a continuous probability distribution, recall that we define the probability as integrals. That means that the probability of an individual point is zero:

$P(X = x)= \int_x^x \lambda e^{- \lambda t} \mathrm dt =0$.

$P(X = x \cap X < c)=0$ in a similar way (it won't *really* matter if $X < c$ or not). If $x < c$ then the integral is reduced to the above. If $x \geq c$ then we calculate $P(\varnothing)=0.$

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured out what was wrong. Since $0 < x < c$, then the intersection of $\{ x\} \cap \{x < c \} = \{ x\}$

Comment: It's true more generally than that. See my answer.

Comment: Yes it appears we may extend this result to other random variables.